# bounded below operators on locally convex spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ two locally convex spaces and $\mathcal{P}_X, \mathcal{P}_Y$ are two  famillies of seminorms generating the topologies of $X$ and $Y$ repsectively.

Let $T: X\longrightarrow Y$ be a linear Operator.

My Question is what is the exact definition (formula using seminorms), so can $T$ be bounded below.